# How do I make "import datetime" only show a day

Tags: python, datetime

So I need a program that tells you what day it is, but any 'datetime' module I find comes with a year and a month, not just day.

```py
import datetime

day = daytime.datetime.now()
print(day)
```

But it prints it like this:

```py
2021-2-25
```

When I need it like this:

```py
25
```

How do I get what I need?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is

```
day = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Doesn't actually give you date only, it gives the timestamp
To get the date, you need to use

```
date = datetime.date.today()
```

Then you can use the corresponding attibute to access that

```
 date.day
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use the `datetime.strftime` classmethod, which converts a `datetime.datetime` object to a string. `datetime.strftime` takes a string which is used as a format code. The individual format codes can be found in the `datetime` documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Since you only want the numerical day of the `datetime` object, you would use the `"%d"` format code. Thus, you code:

```py
import datetime

day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d")
print(day)
```

Comment: That really helped! Appreciated!